# ICC segfaulting with variable length arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, icc

So, when compiled with the basic `icc bob.cpp -o bob` and run, the following code segfaults:

```
#include <string>

int foo () {
  return 6;
}

int main() {
  std::string t[foo()];
}
```

The following two similar programs, however, seem to run fine.

```
#include <string>

int foo () {
  return 6;
}

int main() {
  int f = foo();
  std::string t[f];
}
```

and

```
#include <string>

int foo () {
  return 6;
}

int main() {
  std::string t[6];
}
```

I'm a bit confused about what's going on. Apparently, variable length arrays are non-standard, and this was a surprise to me since I've always used g++ which supports it.  However, if it's not supported by ICC, why would it compile?  Also, why would example 2 "work"?

What is correct code here, and, if the first snippet is incorrect, why does it compile, and then why does it segfault?

I'm using icc (ICC) 12.0.2 20110112 on 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know how you got this to compile with icc since this is C++ code.

Comment: Never mind, I saw icc and didn't notice the .cpp extension you used. Which makes icc use icpc.

Comment: Looks like a bug. What about `std::vector<std::string>> t(f())` as workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, while it is true that C++ has no variable-length arrays (C99 does though), apparently ICC does support them as an extension, since your code actually *compiles* (and since your second snippet actually runs without crashing).

If the first version crashes, then it must be a bug in ICC's implementation of that non-standard extension.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Turned on -pedantic in g++ and cleared up all the issues with nonstandard extensions (lot of arrays became vectors) and now it seems to compile/run fine with the intel compiler.  It's not entirely clear how to submit a bug report to intel, so I guess I'll just let it go... Thanks again.